# C++ Multi-Dimensional Arrays bad excess code

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Im trying to create a matrix with different dimensions and it works fine for a 5 by 3 or a 3 by 3 but if i try making a 2 by 3 matrix then I get a bad excess code. In other words if i try to make my x smaller than my y in my (x,y) pair then I get bad excess.

In my header file I have:

```
#ifndef fasdf_dynn_h
#define fasdf_dynn_h

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template <class T>

class MatrixdynVector{

public:
    MatrixdynVector();
    MatrixdynVector(int m,int n);
    MatrixdynVector(T diagonal, int n, int m);

    template <class H>
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const MatrixdynVector<H> &obj);

private:
    int m,n;
    int** matrix;
};


#endif
```

and in my cpp file I have:

```
#include "dynn.h"

template <class T>
MatrixdynVector<T>::MatrixdynVector(){

    //creates a 3 by 3 matrix with elements equal to 0
    m=3;
    n=3;

    matrix=new int*[m];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        matrix[i]=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            matrix[i][j]=0;


}

template <class T>
MatrixdynVector<T>::MatrixdynVector(int x,int y)
{
    //creates a matrix with dimensions m and n with elements equal to 0

    m=x;
    n=y;

    matrix=new int*[m];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        matrix[i]=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            matrix[i][j]=0;
}


template <class T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const MatrixdynVector<T> & obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.n; j++)
            outs << " "<< obj.matrix[i][j];
        outs<<endl;
    }
    outs<<endl;
    return outs;
}

int main()
{
    MatrixdynVector<int> B;//works fine
    MatrixdynVector<int> A(2,3);//bad excess 


    cout<<B;
    cout<<A;
}
```

Comment: Excess? Access? Where is your destructor? And why don´t you use vectors?

Comment: @deviantfan I already did this with vectors but I need to do this with dynamic array and the destructor is not the issue at the moment

Answer (score 1):

When you create the matrix in the two constructors, the internal loop initialized `j` but then it increments `i`. I think that is the problem.

I would suggest also a different way to allocate the matrix:

```
int *data = new int[m * n];
int **matrix = new int*[m];
for (int r = 0; r < m; ++r)
    matrix[r] = &(data[r * n]);
```

I assumed you have m rows and n columns. You do less allocations and to clean it up you just delete `matrix` and `data` pointers.

Comment: I fixed the internal loop part but whats wrong with the way I allocated the matrix? Also fixing the loop still gives me bad excess code

Comment: About the allocations, your way is working perfectly fine, it's only less efficient: every allocation has a cost, moreover you allocate each rows separately meaning that the matrix will not be contiguous in memory. If you need to scan all the matrix many times, it's better having it contiguous in memory.

Comment: You can assign a _int_ to a _int *_ in the block

_matrix[r] = data[r * n];_

_invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’_

Comment: @guploo please either delete the third constructor from the header file or implement it (you can leave it empty)

Comment: @Arrigo I just figured out my error though I dont know why it does that but I messed up in my constructor with my for loop. Also the third function is irrelevent but i think rod already knows that

Comment: I don't think there was a problem with your for loop: I just copied and pasted your code and it works perfectly fine with g++ (5.1 and 4.8) and clang (3.6). Out of curiosity, let me know what it was